# *.*.companyname.com SSL certificates, what to ask for and what to watch-out for

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

We want to use wildcard.wildcard.companyname.com certificates with our IIS(on Rackspace-managed AWS) based SAAS application, however, though I am technical I do not know what to ask for nor what to watch out for.

I tried Google but the results are full of SSL vendors selling their wares rather than pages giving me answers!

Could anyone share their experiences or good resources to look at?

I have found something called a "Multi-Domain SSL" is that the correct thing for what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

**There is no such certificates supporting  wildcard.wildcard.companyname.com.** 
Common certificate support single domain. For extending use scope, certificate also support multi-domain and second-level domain.
SSL certificate support second-level domain.For exampe, wildcard.xxx.companyname.com.
So the right solution maybe is that certificate support multi second-level domain  *.xxx.companyname.com and *.yyy.companyname.com, *.zzz.companyname.com,...